# Interpretting nested yaml with hiera?

Tags: yaml, puppet, hierarchy, hiera

I saw a lot of questions close to this but not exactly with what I am asking, so please help me out on this. In my yaml file I have a hierarchy such as

```
## application.yaml
application::params::api:
  consumers:
    app1:
      id:  'appname1'
      key: 'key1'
    app2:
      id:  'appname2'
      key: 'key2'
```

Then in the applications params

```
## params.pp
class application::params {
    $application = hiera('application::params::api->????->app1->???->id')
}
```

The question marks are whatever I am using to run onto the next level of hierarchy, I'm uncertain as what my separators should be? I see this sprinkled throughout our code, but cannot find an example of how it is loaded / called into hiera

Would I just use `$application = hiera('application::params::api::app1::id')` ?

Comment: what does the puppet code look like for the class/define that will consume this yaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `::` notation is Puppet specific and have no special meaning to Hiera but it is possible to navigate into details using dotted keys. The expression `hiera('application::params::api.consumers.app1.id')` will return the value 'appname1' when using the data from your example.

More information about Hiera [Lookup Keys](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/latest/lookup_types.html#lookup-keys).

Comment: are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. I wrote the code that resolves such keys in Hiera.

Answer (score 0):

you should take advantage of the [create_resources](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources) function and probably use a [define](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_defined_types.html) rather than a [class](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html) to make it repeatable.

Example follows:

```
# application/init.pp
class application {
  create_resources('application::app', hiera('application::apps'))
}

# application/app.pp
define application::app(id, key) {
  # do stuff with id and key
}
```

This is a bad example and your entire concept strays from best practices. But this should with some research get you to where you are looking to be.

Hope it was helpful.